# VueJS - Accessing store data inside mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble understanding the following:

I have a `store` which contains variables needed for the application. In particular, there is a `globalCompanies` which stores:

```
globalCompanies: {
   current: [],
   all: [],
   currentName: "",
}
```

Inside another component, I want to do the following:

```
mounted() {
   this.$store.dispatch( "fetchUsers" );

   var currentName = this.$store.state.globalCompanies.currentName; 

   console.log(currentName); 
},
```

However, this just shows as empty. I know the value is there because I have `computed` which returns the `currentName` and it works fine inside the view itself. It just doesn't like the fact that it's in the mounted component.

Where am I going wrong and what can I do to resolve this issue? I really need to capture the companies Name in order to use it for some real time events.

Comment: Is `state.globalCompanies.currentName` set by this async call "fetchUsers"?

Comment: @wostex No, it's set by another async call which happens when you load the page. It's in a different component

Comment: Try retrieving the `currentName` in a computed property as you said its working there and use that computed property in the `mounted()` hook

Comment: @VAMSI KRISHNA - Tried this. You cannot access it inside `mounted()` it just shows an empty object. However, inside the view, I have the following: `Search {{this.current}}` which shows the correct value. However doing `console.log(this.current);` just shows an empty object inside `mounted()` :(

Comment: You code should work, otherwise your value is not initialized before `mounted` hook runs. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/u2yoLgLb/2/ if the value is already there all 3 approaches work.

Comment: @wostex This works. But you're setting the state before hand. The state in this case is set through a async method previously. If I set `currentName = "stackoverflow";` inside the store and then do what you do, it returns "stackoverflow" ok -- It's just not returning the async value from ajax request on mounted

Comment: @Phorce well, obviously `mounted` hook runs prior your async call resolves. Computed property handles this: when data arrives computed property updates too. But in `mounted` you get empty value because it's not there yet (mounted runs only once).

Comment: @wostex - How can I handle this then? For example, I have a method called `listen` which needs to get this computed value. The only way I can call this method is through `mounted` ?

Comment: @wostex The `updated` seems to be working fine. Therefore, can I put a listen event into here?

Comment: @Phorce well, you know better what your code does. Another option is to `watch` your computed property and trigger listener when the value of this computed property changes.

Comment: @Phorce I've created an example of using `watch` with `computed` in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

As a result of our discussion:

In the question Vuex state value, accessed in component's `mounted` hook, returns empty value, because it is set in an async action which does not resolve before `mounted` executes.

When you need to trigger some function when async action in Vuex resolves with a value, you can achieve it using `watch` on a computed property, which returns a value from your Vuex state. When a value in store changes, the computed property reflects these changes and `watch` listener executes:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    globalCompanies: {
      test: null
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setMe: (state, payload) => {
      state.globalCompanies.test = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    pretendFetch: ({commit}) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        commit('setMe', 'My text is here!')
      }, 300)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    cp: function() { // computed property will be updated when async call resolves
      return this.$store.state.globalCompanies.test;
    }
  },
  watch: { // watch changes here
    cp: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      // apply your logic here, e.g. invoke your listener function
      console.log('was: ', oldValue, ' now: ', newValue)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('pretendFetch');
    // console.log(this.cp, this.$store.state.globalCompanies.test); // null
    // var cn = this.$store.state.globalCompanies.test; // null
    // console.log(cn) // null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.3.1"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ cp }}
</div>
```

Comment: @RupeshTerase yes, read the answer carefully. You can use `watch` and manipulate value in a callback.

Comment: watch - this is it! Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution. Was searching for hours how to solve this. watch works and seems to be the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

**VueJS - Accessing Store Data Inside Mounted**

Ran into this issue and it turned out to be a scope issue.

**Store:**

```
export default () => {
     items:[],
     globalCompanies:{
        current:[],
        all:[],
        currentName: "Something"
     },
     ok: "Here you go"
}
```

**Getters:**

```
export default {
   getGlobalCompanies(state){
      return state.globalCompanies;
   }
}
```

**Mounted:** This works...

```
mounted() {
   // Initialize inside mounted to ensure store is within scope
   const { getters } = this.$store; 

   const thisWorks = () => {
      const globalCompanies = getters.getGlobalCompanies;
   }
},
```

**This is Bad:** Reaching for the store outside the mounted scope

```
mounted() {
   function ThisDontWork() {
      const { getters } = this.$store; // this.$store == undefined
   }

   ThisDontWork();
},
```