# how to get data in Vuex store in mounted or created function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

i stored data  in vuex but  when i change the  route (component) and i want to access my vuex store (inside mounted function) but  it show  me error and don't return the data how i can fix it?

i know when i use timer it work but it is not the  good  way!
this is my code

```
var timer = setInterval( ()=>{
                    if(typeof this.$store.getters.user === 'undefined'){
                    }else{
                        this.user=this.$store.getters.user
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            },
```

i want return it without the timer, how i can do that?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the mounted hook is executing before the async vuex function resolves.

Check out this answer - [VueJS - Accessing store data inside mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324454/vuejs-accessing-store-data-inside-mounted)

It explains how you could use `watch` to trigger a function when the async function resolves.